# Length of a Curve and Integration

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Two different integration questions are baffling me right now, and I have no idea how to approach them:

The first deals with finding the length of the curve $$ y = \int_{-2}^x sqrt(3t^4-1)dt$$

The second is (probably) a very simple integration problem that I can't get because my mind is now muddled with more complicated equations. It's part of a larger problem also involving length of a curve, but I can work it out after I figure this out:

$$ \int_t^1 sqrt(1+ (4/9)x^{(-2/3)})dx $$

Your help is much appreciated! I've been trying to solve them for the past hour and haven't gotten anywhere.

Comment: The first one is an "elliptic integral" ... look it up.

Comment: We haven't covered elliptic integrals in the course I'm taking, so there should be a simpler way to solve it. 

Do I need to solve the integral and then use the formula for arc length, L = integral sqrt(1+(dy/dx)^2?

Comment: So, since you cannot evaluate the integral, maybe you can compute $dy/dx$ without doing it!

Comment: Oh, I think I get it! because the function being integrated is already dy/dx, so I just plug that into my equation! Will the bounds -2 and x affect it at all if it's within the range -2<=x<=-1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your second problem, if $x$ is positive, we have
$$\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{9}x^{-2/3}}=\frac{1}{3x^{1/3}}\sqrt{9x^{2/3}+4}.$$
To integrate, let $u=9x^{2/3}+4$. If we are integrating over an interval where $x$ is negative, $\frac{1}{3x^{1/3}}$ should be replaced by $-\frac{1}{3x^{1/3}}$.

Comment: So then I get 1/18du = (1/3)x^(-1/3), and (1/18)integral u^(1/2), and finally:
$$ (1/27)(9x^{2/3}+4)^{3/2} $$  
Is that right?

Comment: Yes, apart from the $+C$.